# Multiple columns and custom bar chart using google or d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, google-visualization

I have a data table in Google Charts which I need to import from mongodb in JS.
if I manage that it would look like this (an extremely small version):

```
    id           date     no    time         amt newamt section    
['16212435', '2015-12-31',4, '6 PM to 12 AM',1,0.017,35],
['16212435', '2015-12-01',2, '12 AM to 6 AM',1,0.017,35],
['16212435', '2015-12-31',4, '9 AM to 3 PM',0,0,35], 
['16212435', '2015-12-01',4, '3 PM to 6 PM',2,0.33,35],
['16212435', '2015-12-31',4, '6 AM to 9 AM',1,0.017,35]
```

I need a bar chart which shows **newamt** on the x axis, id on the y axis.
For multiple values of same id, it needs to be stacked on basis of date.

Can this be possible with google stacked bar chart? if not, any approach suggestions with d3?
Please help.

Comment: sounds possible with google -- can you clarify _stacked on basis of date_? if you have __newamt__ on the x, and the values stacked for each id, i'm lost on the date -- have a mockup image or anything?

Comment: I meant they they need to be color coded by 'no'. On the sample I have, they are stacked in order of the no...